# Передать данные из ListBox и memo на первой форме во вторую форму в виде таблицы

Tags: c++builder, c++

Помогите, пожалуйста, нужно передать данные из ListBox (правый на скрине с 1 студентом) и memo (С описанием этого студента) на первой форме во вторую форму в виде таблицы и напечатать эту таблицу.

Скриншот программы:

[image]

Все данные загружаются из текстовых документов.

Код кнопки Сведения:

```
if (ListBox2->ItemIndex == -1) {exit;}

ListBox2->ItemIndex = 0;

if (ListBox2->Items->Strings[ListBox2->ItemIndex] == AnsiString("Васин А.В."))
{
Memo3->Lines->Clear();
Memo3->Lines->LoadFromFile("texts/vasin.txt");
}
if (ListBox2->Items->Strings[ListBox2->ItemIndex] == AnsiString("Иванов С.И"))
{
Memo3->Lines->Clear();
Memo3->Lines->LoadFromFile("texts/ivanov.txt");
}
if (ListBox2->Items->Strings[ListBox2->ItemIndex] == AnsiString("Петров Д.П."))
{
Memo3->Lines->Clear();
Memo3->Lines->LoadFromFile("texts/petrov.txt");
}
if (ListBox2->Items->Strings[ListBox2->ItemIndex] == AnsiString("Сидоров В.С."))
{
Memo3->Lines->Clear();
Memo3->Lines->LoadFromFile("texts/sidorov.txt");
}
if (ListBox2->Items->Strings[ListBox2->ItemIndex] == AnsiString("Степанов А.С."))
{
Memo3->Lines->Clear();
Memo3->Lines->LoadFromFile("texts/stepanov.txt");
}
```

Comment: А если количество студентов = 1000? Так и будет Ваш код подрастать? Это что-то не то. Подумайте над его оптимизацией.

Comment: Дана задача, нужно решить, про будущее ничего не говорилось

Answer (score 1):

Храните указатель на вторую форму в первой, через него будет доступ к элементам. Указатель нужно объявить на базовый класс Form, не Form2

Comment: Плохой ответ,точнее не полный, приводить потом через static_cast к нужному типу надо https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_cast